# Calculate overlapping track segments

Tags: python, geospatial, postgis, spatial

My goal is to achieve something similiar to the Strava Global Heatmap Feature. So basically calculating heatmaps for tracks coming from GPX sources.

Lets say i have two GPX Files. I managed to import them via ogr2ogr as MultiLine Strings into a PostGIS database. Now i have two rows in my tracks table with the following geometry:

```
{"type":"MultiLineString","coordinates":[[[11.363516,47.655794],[11.364301,47.655176],[11.364413,47.655137],[11.364871,47.654996],[11.365184,47.654925],[11.365453,47.655203],[11.365938,47.655518],[11.36609,47.655665],[11.366221,47.655918]]]}
{"type":"MultiLineString","coordinates":[[[11.364048,47.654866],[11.364423,47.655141],[11.364881,47.655],[11.365189,47.654965],[11.365542,47.654859],[11.365846,47.654845],[11.365935,47.654849]]]}
```

Those two tracks share (at least if you allow some tolerance) a portion of their segments:
[image: tracks visualised]

If i would analyse something like 100-200 tracks, some of them would share some segments, others would not.

My goal would be to find those shared segments, (throw away one of the segments) and to increase the "heat"/"count" in a different column.

I assume Strava is doing this [on a point level](https://medium.com/strava-engineering/the-global-heatmap-now-6x-hotter-23fc01d301de). This works having billions of data points, but for my personal it doesn't look good to just take the normal track_points and do a "normal" heatmap calculation there.

Some of the information i found for calculating this with spatial operations are over 5-8 years old, so i hope there is any slightly comfortable solution doing this either in some framework or via Postgis ST calculations or some python coding.

Any ideas on that?

Comment: I'd be tempted to make a hex grid, then count the number of tracks intersecting each hex.

Comment: @mlinth Nice idea. But if I do this on a hexagon grid with scale of 0.00005 and 150 tracks the query runs 10 minutes, takes up 40 GB of disk space and then runs out of storage / space. So this seems computational very expensive.

Answer (score 0):

One approach you could use is [map matching](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_matching) and then you can simply count the number of the same edge ids/osm ids when you loop over the responses. This is only of course possible if your geometries represent roads or paths that are present in OpenStreetMap. Have a look at [Valhalla](https://valhalla.github.io/valhalla/api/map-matching/api-reference/). They have a [free API](https://github.com/valhalla/valhalla#demo-server) you can use for this use case and let it do the heavy lifting for you. In the response you will find the way IDs. From the docs

> You can turn a GPS trace into a set of way IDs that match the trace.

This should give you enough to compute the *count* that you asked for.